# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException on api19

Tags: android, gradle

I got this exception

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016
```

i try to get this icon in

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
// ofc i used full path to support-v7 library icon, but i hadnt access to my code right now :(
```

Gradle version 2.1
Android support libraries version 24.2.0
Exception appears on api19 (4.4.4)

adding to defaultConfig this line didnt solve issue

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Copying icon to my drawable directory didnt solve issue too

Maybe who know some tricks to avoid this exception?

Comment: With `useSupportLibrary `, shouldn't the declaration be: `android.R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material`?

Comment: I edited question.
I use android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material .

is it will be solved if i will use android.R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material ?

Sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: Did [this](https://imgur.com/a/g7mdk) error to you too?

Comment: Yes, i had this notice from ide. but copying to my own drawable folder didnt help

Comment: Copy the drawable in proper folders and then reference it using `R.drawable. abc_ic_ab_back_material`...that should definitely work.

Comment: I tried it. But it didnt solve my issue. Will try it again later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the drawable to project res folder solved issue. Thanks for Shaishav